# Symfony2 How To Change The Form ID

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a form field that I want to change the ID on when rendering in Twig. For some reason it is not adding the ID to the form field.

Here is how I am doing this in Twig:

```
 {{ form_widget(form.purchaseOrderLineItem, { 'value': value, 'id': 'new_id',  'attr': {'style': 'display:none'} }) }}
```

Here is what it is outputting:

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="203543" />
```

Why is it not creating the form field with the ID?

Comment: `{{ form_widget(form.lastName, { 'value': 'test', 'id': 'new_id',  'attr': {'style': 'display:none'} }) }}` I tested it on my form and the id field is changed.

Comment: What does your form_row and field_widget template look like for Twig? When I remove my form theme everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Shouldn't the `id` be in the `attr`object? (sorry can't test right now)

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to add an id attribute, because he hardcode in the template [form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1d86ea10ffa7bfa4cd89593a715890afa783feb7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L373). But you can override it like this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block widget_attributes %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if attr.id is not defined %}id="{{ id }}"{% endif %} name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
        {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}{% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` need to be in `attr` section:

```
{{ form_widget(form.purchaseOrderLineItem, { 'value': value,  'attr': {'style': 'display:none', 'id':'new_id'} }) }}
```